# iOS view controller containment | Child View Controller passes touches to Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

In `iOS5`, I use `UIViewController` containment all over an app where I have implemented `UITouchGesture` in several places.

When I add a child `ViewController` (Full Screen) the touches are passed down to its parent.

What, if any, is the solution around this. I use `MPFlipViewController` and I can see the page turning underneath the child when the user moves their finger across the the Child `ViewController`.

For clarification, I add my ViewController as a child with the following:

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.container addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The container is merely just a UIView that the view of the childViewController & other UIView objects sit on. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got it backwards. Controller containment is one thing, but this is just standard view hierarchy and responder chain stuff. So the touches are initially sent to the parent; specifically a call is made to its view's `-(UIView *)hitTest:withEvent:`. That returns a child view if one can be found. Otherwise it returns one of its own views. Possibly it returns itself.

If a touch is being captured by the parent controller that means it's never been sent to the child. Not that it's being sent to the child then ascending up to the parent.

If you want the parent to do something unusual with touch capture then just use a custom view and implement your own `-hitTest:withEvent:`. As a first step, do that and just log the inputs to see what happens.

Comment: Ive modified my question, its not standard View Hierachy stuff as i add the ViewController as a childViewController who still passes their touches to a UIView Object on the parent from which it descends from :) .

Comment: Unless you're manually passing the touches in that direction, that's not how UIKit works. The search to find the most local view underneath a touch descends from the topmost view downwards. So from parent to child. Not vice versa. Controller containment adds to normal view management, it doesn't change the fundamentals. How do you think the view underneath a touch is found?

Answer (score 1):

It's imposiible before iOS 7 release, and I want to know wheather any gurus get this done now.

Comment: So what do i do in iOS7 to stop that? Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You should implement touch handling for the child view controller. Allow the child to capture all touch events, and then drop them so that they're not passed to the parent.

One other solution could be to wrap your child view controller in a `UINavigationController`, that might get you the behavior for free.

It might be helpful for you to post your `UITouchGesture` code from the parent view controller.

Answer (score 1):

In `MPFlipViewController.m` you should look at this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // don't recognize simultaneously with scroll view gestures in content area
    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer view] isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        return NO;

    // Allow simultanoues pan & swipe recognizers
    return YES;
}
```

Change it to something like

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // don't recognize simultaneously with scroll view gestures in content area
    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer view] isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        return NO;

    if (otherGestureRecognizer == GestureRecognizerOfYourChildViewController)
        return NO;

    // Allow simultanoues pan & swipe recognizers
    return YES;
}
```

Where of course GestureRecognizerOfYourChildViewController is your child view controller's gesture recognizer.

EDIT: Since OP is not using gesture recognizers on his own child view controller, the solution is a bit different. I'll leave the first version here though because it might be helpful for others with similar problem.

Best solution I can think of here is that you need to disable gestureRecognizers in `MPFlipViewController` when there is a child view controller displayed over it and enable them again when the child view controller is removed and `MPFlipViewController` is on top again. Use the `enabled` property for that.

Gesture recognizers work outside the "touch chain" that you use in your own view controller, that's why your problem is happening.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question slightly, Im not using a gesture recogniser on the ChildViewController, the user is simply placing their finger across the screen in the child view and the MPFlipViewController which is on the parent is absorbing the touch and moving the 'page'

Comment: I updated the answer. But does the child view controller react to the touches it receives?